# The best way to merge multi-nested dictionaries in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, merge

I have two nested dictionaries and I want to merge them into one (where second dict overrides first dict values). I saw a lot of beautiful solutions for merging "flat" (not nested) dictionaries, e.g.:

```
dict_result = dict1.copy()
dict_result.update(dict2)
```

or

```
dict_result = dict(dict1.items() + dict2.items())
```

or (my favorit one)

```
dict_result = dict(d1,**d2)
```

but couldn't find the most efficient way to merge multi-nested dicts.

I'm trying to avoid recursion. What is your proposition?

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid recursion." Good luck with that!

Comment: I hope, that Python offers some built-in method for this case, but never seen anything what would be good for my purposes.

Comment: You can turn any recursive solution into an iterative solution just by using a loop with an explicit stack…

Comment: By the way, your favorite one is really the worst of the three, because it fails if any of d2's keys aren't strings. Although the second one isn't great either, because it builds three unnecessary lists; `dict(itertools.chain(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()))` avoids that. Of course 90% of the time, you don't even need a new dict, and `ChainMap` would be simpler and more efficient… But anyway, this is all off-topic for your question.

Answer (score 15):

Unless the depth of the dictionaries to merge is strictly limited, there's no way to avoid recursion.<sup>1)</sup> Also, there's no bultin or library function to do this (that is, none that I know of), but it's actually not all that hard. Something like this should do:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    for k in d2:
        if k in d1 and isinstance(d1[k], dict) and isinstance(d2[k], dict):
            merge(d1[k], d2[k])
        else:
            d1[k] = d2[k]
```

What this does: It iterates the keys in `d2` and if the key can also be found in `d1` and both are dictionaries, merge those sub-dictionaries, otherwise overwrite the value in `d1` with that from `d2`. Note that this changes `d1` and its sub-dictionaries *in place*, so you might want to deep-copy it before.

Or use this version to create a merged copy:

```
def merge_copy(d1, d2):
    return {k: merge_copy(d1[k], d2[k]) if k in d1 and isinstance(d1[k], dict) and isinstance(d2[k], dict) else d2[k] for k in d2}
```

Example:

```
>>> d1 = {"foo": {"bar": 23, "blub": 42}, "flub": 17}
>>> d2 = {"foo": {"bar": 100}, "flub": {"flub2": 10}, "more": {"stuff": 111}}
>>> merge(d1, d2)
>>> print d1
{'foo': {'bar': 100, 'blub': 42}, 'flub': {'flub2': 10}, 'more': {'stuff': 111}}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> You *can* make it iterative, using a stack, but this will only make things more complicated and should only be done to avoid problems with maximum recursive depth.

Comment: This is a recursive in-place update, not a recursive copying merge like the OP asked for… but it should be dead obvious how to transform one into the other, even if you didn't make it explicit in your explanation. :)

Comment: Thank you! But one little remark (if someone would like to use this code) - in merge_copy() arguments should be switched, and correct call of this function should be: merge_copy(d2, d1) :)

Comment: @mchfrnc Are you sure? The function seems to work correctly. Or just so that `merge(d2, d1)` reads more like "merge d2 into d1"? I also thought about that, but since you said that "the second" should overwrite "the first", I put the "overwriting" dict in the second position.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of the above `merge_copy` function for dicts that can be thought of as merging parent and child where you want the parent to inherit all the values from child to create a new dict.

```
def merge_copy(child, parent):
    '''returns parent updated with child values if exists'''
    d = {}
    for k in parent:
        if k in child and isinstance(child[k], dict) and isinstance(parent[k], dict):
            v = merge_copy(child[k], parent[k])
        elif k in child:
            v = child[k]
        else:
            v = parent[k]
        d[k] = v
    return d
```

Comment: This answer drops any keys unique to the child dictionary as it iterates over the parent's set of keys without also including keys unique to the child.  Suggest you iterate over `set().union(parent, child)`