# Need to form update dict in loop

Tags: python, json, csv

My CSV file is as below:

```
destination_name,destination_code,destination_arrival_scheduled,destination_arrival_actual,origin_name,origin_code,origin_departure_scheduled,origin_departure_actual,train_date,train_code
Pune,Pun,11:50:00,11:52:05,Delhi,Del,10:30:00,10:30:18,17-Jan-17,D220
Mumbai,mum,11:50:00,11:52:05,Delhi,Del,10:30:00,10:30:18,17-Jan-17,D320
Delhi,del,11:50:00,11:52:05,Indore,Ind,10:30:00,10:30:18,17-Jan-17,D320

need to from Json as below
[
  {
    "origin": {
      "code": "Del", 
      "name": "Delhi", 
      "departure": {
        "scheduled": "10:30:00", 
        "diff": "0:00:18", 
        "actual": "10:30:18"
      }
    }, 
    "destination": {
      "arrival": {
        "scheduled": "11:50:00", 
        "diff": "0:02:05", 
        "actual": "11:52:05"
      }, 
      "code": "Pun", 
      "name": "Pune"
    }, 
    "train": {
      "date": "17-Jan-17", 
      "code": "D220"
    }
  }
```

below is my code Python code

```
import csv,itertools,json,re
csvfile =open("C:\\Users\\Amit\\train_data.csv","r")
json_file = "C:\\Users\\Amit\\file.json";

data = []
obj ={}
train={}

for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
    train['date']=row['train_date']
    #print(train)
    data.append(train)
print(data)
```

The data has correct number of elements but the data is updated with last record. Please help me to store the all the values in the train{} in data[]?

Comment: Hi @Amit, I think it's hard to understand the question the way it is phrased.

Comment: I think it's quite clear. You need to parse dates, calculate differences and create a nested dict.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` which extracts data from a nested array of dictionaries I thought we could do something similar but reverted:

```
data = '''\
destination_name,destination_code,destination_arrival_scheduled,destination_arrival_actual,origin_name,origin_code,origin_departure_scheduled,origin_departure_actual,train_date,train_code
Pune,Pun,11:50:00,11:52:05,Delhi,Del,10:30:00,10:30:18,17-Jan-17,D220
Mumbai,mum,11:50:00,11:52:05,Delhi,Del,10:30:00,10:30:18,17-Jan-17,D320
Delhi,del,11:50:00,11:52:05,Indore,Ind,10:30:00,10:30:18,17-Jan-17,D320'''

import pandas as pd
import json

dates = ['destination_arrival_actual', 'destination_arrival_scheduled', 
         'origin_departure_actual', 'origin_departure_scheduled','train_date']

# Read your data to a pandas Dataframe (and parse dates)
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),parse_dates=dates)

# Create new columns with diff in seconds
df['destination_arrival_diff'] = round((df[dates[0]]-df[dates[1]]).dt.total_seconds())
df['origin_departure_diff'] = round((df[dates[2]]-df[dates[3]]).dt.total_seconds())

# Define a merge function
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/29847323/7386332
def merge(d1, d2):
    for k in d2:
        if k in d1 and isinstance(d1[k], dict) and isinstance(d2[k], dict):
            merge(d1[k], d2[k])
        else:
            d1[k] = d2[k] 

# Loop through rows and add dictionaries to array output
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135649/7386332
splitkey = "_"
output = []
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    d = {}
    for k in row.index:
        merge(d,reduce(lambda res, cur: {cur: res}, reversed(k.split(splitkey)), str(row[k])))
    output.append(d)

print(json.dumps(output,indent=2))
```

Returns:

```
[
  {
    "destination": {
      "name": "Pune",
      "code": "Pun",
      "arrival": {
        "actual": "2017-12-10 11:52:05",
        "scheduled": "2017-12-10 11:50:00",
        "diff": "125.0"
      }
    },
    "origin": {
      "name": "Delhi",
      "code": "Del",
      "departure": {
        "actual": "2017-12-10 10:30:18",
        "scheduled": "2017-12-10 10:30:00",
        "diff": "18.0"
      }
    },
    "train": {
      "code": "D220",
      "date": "2017-01-17 00:00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "destination": {
      "name": "Mumbai",
      "code": "mum",
      "arrival": {
        "actual": "2017-12-10
...
}
```